# How to generate an index dictionary from a list of items in C# using linq and lambda

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, lambda

The following code gives me the indexed dictionary I want (I want to have the position of the items in the list handy), but is there a way to do this more directly? Perhaps without the "Select" portion? And is the "new" object needed to create the dictionary elements?

```
var Fruits = new List<string> { "apple", "peach", "starwberry" };
var fruitDict = Fruits.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).ToDictionary(e => e.index, e => e.value);
```

Also considered Lookup, how might that work if it is a better option.  Other options for having the index position of a list item handy in other parts of the code?

Comment: Give an example of what the data would look like before and after

Comment: `ToLookup` is really meant to handle the case of duplicate keys so you get a collection of items for a key.  And there isn't a more straight forward way to do that with Linq.  At least not one that's inefficient and error prone.

Comment: Is this a fixed list?  Or does it grow dynamically?  Also, why?  You can always get the index from the list object, and if you're putting the items into the list first, you'll have to enforce uniqueness there, or the dictionary will have errors on duplicate keys.  The dictionary seems needless overhead in this particular case.  If it grows dynamically why not overload the Add() method with one that locates the next index and then put the entry directly into the dictionary, skipping the list all together.

Comment: Whats the problem with the Select function? Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: example data "before" is the List "Fruits"

Comment: On the other side why don't you use Fruits[index] with your list? When your keys are indexes you can treat your list as a dictionary really.

Comment: "after" is the Dictionary "fruitDict", which has the same fruits, in the same order, with list index postion as a key.

This list is fixed, not going to add to it during processing.  I will be storing the dictionary elements elsewhere and will need to return relative index positions of multiple of the original list elements at a time, so I understand, on a one by one basis, I can get a given list index, but this is not convenient in the general solution.

There should be no duplicate keys if the keys are just the indexes of the elements of the original list. keys are unique.

Comment: I'm guessing the Select statement is needed.  I'm ok with it... I was just curious if there was a simpler statement for what I wrote.

Comment: The Select() runs in the iterator "lazy" (when needed) so it does not cost you additional memory or so. The other question still is: why do you need all indexes separately? You can access "Fruites" directly by index like ``Fruits[3]``. I guess, if you show us what goal you try to achieve with that dictionary we can help a lot more.

Comment: @Eelke Perhaps you should ask another question: your explanation isn't very clear, or perhaps your `Dictionary` is backwards, otherwise I can think of nothing about your `Dictionary` that can't be handled just as easily/quickly with the original `List`.

Answer (score 1):

As @arekzyla noted, it makes little sense to create a `Dictionary` indexed by list position when you can just reference the list by position directly, however, if you really want to, you can avoid creating new anonymous objects by using an outside variable and an expression with a side effect:

```
var index = 0;
var fruitDict = Fruits.ToDictionary(f => index++, f => f);
```